# Изменение цвета блока при наведении на другой

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Пытаюсь сделать меню. Вопрос в том , что когда я навожу на элемент `Menu1` или другой, появляется выпадающий список, пока в этот момент `menu1` изменяет цвет `background` на тот который я указал.

Когда я перевожу фокус в выпадающий блок, цвет `background` `menu1` становиться дефолтным, а нужно чтобы он оставался тем, который был при наведении и оставался до того момента пока фокус находится в выпавшем блоке.

Пытался написать так, но не работает:

```
ul.submenu > li > a:hover >(~,+(пробовал различные варианты)) ul.menu > li >a {
    background-color: #ffff9c;
}
```

пробовал менять условие, но все никак не работает, код меню ниже:

```css
ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul:after {
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}
ul.menu > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
ul.menu > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.menu > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #ffff9c;
}
ul.submenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    top: 37px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
ul.submenu > li {
    display: block;
}
ul.submenu > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    background-color: #ffff9c;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.submenu > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
ul.menu > li:hover > ul.submenu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href=#>Menu 1</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href=#>Menu 2</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить:

```
ul.menu > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #ffff9c;
}
```

на

```
ul.menu > li:hover a {
    background-color: #ffff9c;
}
```

Comment: о боже так просто , а я голову сломал, спасибо